# How to weigh the size of a spatial event with respect to the number of its hotspots?

Tags: cartography, map-algebra, weighted-overlay

This is probably a *map algebra* problem. I have a 2D map with values ranging `0.0` to `1.0` spread all over it. The algorithm that produces them is an application of the [fractional Brownian motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_Brownian_motion). The map measures `101x101` pixels or cells.

**My problem:** I want to find in the map the regions (or islands) which values exceed a given threshold, e.g. `0.3` (we can call them the *hotspots*). I then want to calculate the number of pixels or cells that fall within the boundaries of that island. Given that there might be more than one island, I could end up with:

1. **Situation 1:** 1 island with, say, `1000` pixels or cells;
2. **Situation 2:** 2 islands with `500` pixels or cells each;
3. Additional combinations.

Since **I must be able to distinguish between the various situations**, I was thinking of somehow **weighing** the total number of cells with respect to the number of islands. How could I do this, other than considering the average number of cells (which I see as a trivial solution)?

I am asking this since if I were to evaluate the impact of those *hotspots* on a system that is *embedded* in the map, there might be huge differences between having one big hotspot located in the center of the map and having multiple, although smaller, hotspots scattered all over the place.

Below is a visual example of what I mean by islands or regions.

[image]

Comment: You want to do this in any particular software?

Comment: I am working in Python.

Comment: would love to figure this out in postgis raster....!!! got any sample data you could post?

Comment: I have a bunch of csv files I can send over... would it work?

Comment: @FC84 I would greatly appreciate it - I'm really trying to figure out PostGIS Raster and this looks like a great workflow to test it out... thank you! (sorry for the delay - holiday week off!)

Comment: How can I catch up with you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most simple way to do this is:

1. Generate contours. You can do this in ArcGiS, QGIS with plugin or even with pure python (but you need to find a proper script or write it by yourself). Generate them with breaks 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 etc.
2. Now all values with 0.3=< are surrounded by 0.3 value line features. Select these lines, create a new layer and convert this layer to polygon.
3. Calculate the min. area of hotspot. Simply get a resolution of raster (V and H pixel size), calculate pixel area and multiply this value by number of pixels in hotspot you want.
4. Iterate by features in your polygons created from 0.3 contour and check if area of feature is greater then a calculated value from point 3. If true, write it to new layer.

And now you should have a polygon layer with your "islands". If you need them as lines or points, simply convert to lines or get centroids.

This is the simple way, other things that you can do are more complicated, for example Radial Basis Functions are nice tools to classification, or maybe other neural network approach would do the job.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Anyhow, this is mostly a GIS procedure for identifying the islands. I already have a procedure for doing this, which is numerical (the map of course is a matrix). What I am after is an aggregate way of evaluating the impact of these events on my system. Which is to say: 1)  I can plot how the response of the system varies with the overall number of cells within the islands; 2) I can plot the response against the number of islands. But I am looking for a sensible way of **condensing** the two plots into one.